# create table with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a Jquery table and the purpose of it is that with each element clicked it shows an alert, but I am not able to make that happen.

The question that was presented to me was the following:
Create a table with at least 5 rows and two columns. for each element td
clicked, execute an event that displays a dialog box (alert) with the id of the
element clicked.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>João Augusto</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="p-5 text-black text-center bg-roxo">
  <h1 id="titulo">João Augusto</h1>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-header">Tabela dinâmica</h1>
            
            <table id="details-table" class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Idade</th>
                <th>CPF</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button> <input type="button" onclick="funcao1()" value="Exibir Alert" /> </td>
                
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                
                <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQUERY (js):

```
(function($) {
    remove = function(item) {
      var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
  
      tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();  
      });
  
      return false;
    }
  })(jQuery);

  function funcao1()
{
alert("Olá!");
}
```

Comment: please help me to make it workable.

Comment: I don't really understand what your objective is. I assume each `<td>` element needs an `id` to into the alert? I hope this example might be helpful to you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/juz9c4hp/

Comment: Your question is not clear but you want a function which give id of that button on which you click first give id to that button then in function use funcao1(event) and in           function funcao1(event) {
                alert("id: " + event.target.id + " value:" + event.target.value);
            } use event.target.id for get id and event.target.value for get value

Comment: When each td element is clicked by the user of the program, the program should show an alert with some message.

Comment: But I am not able to make each td element show an alert when clicked.

Comment: your example meets my problem to some extent. But he doesn't have Bootstrap.